# Workflow Foundation .NET 4 learning resources

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

Can you recommend some resources (web or book) providing an introduction to Windows Workflow Foundation in .NET 4? Basic introduction is what I need at the moment but I would also very appreciate advanced-level materials. Thanks!

Comment: +1 To that. I though there would be more out there by now.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely take a look at this [blog](https://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/). There is a lot of articles about WF 3 and 4, the guy is really doing a great job.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely look at the MS PDC from the last couple to years.